# Remove onKeyup Event handler on input fields

Tags: jquery, opencart, jquery-events, onkeyup

I have a form on an admin panel of opencart that will work out the total product costs and will break down the cost.

I have 3 editable fields and a total field.

The whole inputs are worked out `onKeyUp`
(this was built by another developer).

I've made some buttons that will autofill the fields with data, but the way its coded, it works out the total `onKeyUp`, now that means if I click my button to auto fill data, I still have to click into a field and press any button (usually Enter) for it to update the total field.

Is there an event handle that will just work it out on the fly, removing the `onKeyUp` function and just working out the total so I don't need to click into a box after I've pressed a button?

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td nowrap="nowrap"><input onKeyUp="totalcost(this.form);" type="text" name="cost" value="<?php echo $cost; ?>" style="text-align:right; background-color: #ffd7d7; border: thin solid #999;" /></td>
    <td width="40" align="center" nowrap="nowrap">=</td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap"><input onKeyUp="totalcost(this.form); if(!this.value) this.value=0; totalcost(this.form);" id="cog" type="text" name="cost_amount" value="<?php echo $cost_amount; ?>" style="border: thin solid #999;" /></td>
    <td width="50" align="center" nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo $text_cost_or; ?></td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap"><input onKeyUp="totalcost(this.form); if(!this.value) this.value=0; totalcost(this.form);" id="perc" type="text" name="cost_percentage" maxlength="5" value="<?php echo $cost_percentage; ?>" style="border: thin solid #999;" />%</td>
    <td width="40" align="center" nowrap="nowrap">+</td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap"><input onKeyUp="totalcost(this.form); if(!this.value) this.value=0; totalcost(this.form);" id="podf" type="text" name="cost_additional" value="<?php echo $cost_additional; ?>" style="border: thin solid #999;" /></td>
    <td width="40" align="center" nowrap="nowrap">+</td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><div id="tabs"><a href="#tab-option"><?php echo $text_cost_option_cost; ?></a></div></td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap"><span class="help"><?php echo $text_cost; ?></span></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap"><span class="help"><?php echo $text_cost_amount; ?></span></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap"><span class="help"><?php echo $text_cost_percentage; ?></span></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap"><span class="help"><?php echo $text_cost_additional; ?></span></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap"><span class="help"><?php echo $text_cost_option; ?></span></td>    
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="POD" id="pod" />
        <input type="button" value="STK" id="stk" />

        <script>
            $(function () {
            $('#pod').on('click', function () {
                var text = $('#perc');
                text.val(0); 
                var text = $('#cog');
                text.val(1.55);   
                var text = $('#podf');
                text.val(3.10);    
            });

            $('#stk').on('click', function () {
                var text = $('#perc');
                text.val(15); 
                var text = $('#cog');
                text.val(0);  
                var text = $('#podf');
                text.val(0);    
            });

             

        });

        </script>

    </td>
  </tr>

  
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need in Your code is to call the `totalcost()` function after setting the values after button click. Let's assume your `<form>` has an ID `form`, then you could do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#pod').on('click', function () {
            var text = $('#perc');
            text.val(0);
            var text = $('#cog');
            text.val(1.55);
            var text = $('#podf');
            text.val(3.10);

            totalcost($('#form'));
        });

        $('#stk').on('click', function () {
            var text = $('#perc');
            text.val(15);
            var text = $('#cog');
            text.val(0);
            var text = $('#podf');
            text.val(0);
            text.val(3.10);

            totalcost($('#form'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note added calls to `totalcost()` where I am passing the `<form id="form">` selector. If Your form has different ID (or does not have ID at all) make sure to adjust the selector (or `<form>` as well).